# Variable en código try/catch siempre devuelve Undefined o vacia en otra función en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, webservice, soap, try-catch

Estoy tratando de hacer un switch de mensajes para el plugin contact form 7 en el que, dependiendo de la excepción que devuelva el cliente Soap, pueda personalizar el mensaje al usuario y para ello he creado este código:

```
try{ 

    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
    //creamos el cliente
    $cliente = new SoapClient("$url", array(
        'login'          => "XXX",
        'password'       => "XXX"
        )
    );
    //hacemos la consulta
    $resultado = $cliente->registrar_usuario($params);

    //añadimos la respuesta personalizada
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output_ok', 10, 4 );

    // EMAIL CON DEBUG (COMENTAR AL FINALIZAR)
    mail_debug($resultado);

}
catch (SoapFault $ex) { 
    $error = $ex->faultcode;

//RESPUESTA ANTE UNA EXCEPCIÓN

function wpse_form_response_output_ko( $output, $class, $content, $instance) {
global $error;

    switch ($error) {
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.IdUsuarioInvalido':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario no es válido.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.UsuarioExistente':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario ya existe.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;

        default:
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: Ha ocurrido un fallo al enviar el formulario, revise bien los campos.'));
            break;
    }
}


    // MOSTRAMOS LA RESPUESTA PERSONALIZADA
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output_ko', 10, 4 );

    // ANULAMOS EMAIL DE CONFIRMACIÓN SI HAY EXCEPCIÓN
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );


    // EMAIL CON DEBUG (COMENTAR AL FINALIZAR)
    mail_debug($ex);

}
```

Pero no hay manera de que funcione la variable `$error` dentro de la función `wpse_form_response_output_ko`, si no la manejo como global me da un error de `undefined` y si la manejo como global, aparece vacia y siempre me da el resultado por defecto del switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que estás sufriendo es debido a que la variable `$error` que has creado no es global, es local al bloque `catch (SoapFault $ex) { ... }` y fuera de ese bloque no existe, por lo que la "otra" variable que intentas acceder no contiene lo que esperas.

---

**Ejemplo usando `global $error`**

En este ejemplo agrego `global $error` en el bloque `catch` para que `$error` apunte a la variable `$error` global al asignarle el error:

```
try { ... }
catch (SoapFault $ex) {
    global $error;
    $error = $ex->faultcode;

//RESPUESTA ANTE UNA EXCEPCIÓN

function wpse_form_response_output_ko( $output, $class, $content, $instance) {
global $error;

    switch ($error) {
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.IdUsuarioInvalido':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario no es válido.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.UsuarioExistente':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario ya existe.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;

        default:
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: Ha ocurrido un fallo al enviar el formulario, revise bien los campos.'));
            break;
    }
}


    // MOSTRAMOS LA RESPUESTA PERSONALIZADA
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output_ko', 10, 4 );

    // ANULAMOS EMAIL DE CONFIRMACIÓN SI HAY EXCEPCIÓN
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );


    // EMAIL CON DEBUG (COMENTAR AL FINALIZAR)
    mail_debug($ex);

}
```

Ahora ambas variables apuntarán a la misma variable global `$error`.

---

**Ejemplo usando `$GLOBALS['error']`**

En este ejemplo hago uso de la variable súperglobal `$GLOBALS` para acceder al contenido de la variable global.

```
try { ... }
catch (SoapFault $ex) {
    $GLOBALS['error'] = $ex->faultcode;

//RESPUESTA ANTE UNA EXCEPCIÓN

function wpse_form_response_output_ko( $output, $class, $content, $instance) {

    switch ($GLOBALS['error']) {
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.IdUsuarioInvalido':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario no es válido.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.UsuarioExistente':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario ya existe.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;

        default:
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: Ha ocurrido un fallo al enviar el formulario, revise bien los campos.'));
            break;
    }
}


    // MOSTRAMOS LA RESPUESTA PERSONALIZADA
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output_ko', 10, 4 );

    // ANULAMOS EMAIL DE CONFIRMACIÓN SI HAY EXCEPCIÓN
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );


    // EMAIL CON DEBUG (COMENTAR AL FINALIZAR)
    mail_debug($ex);

}
```

---

**Ejemplo usando `$GLOBALS[__FILE__ . '_error']`**

Hay casos en los que elegimos usar una variable global que está siendo usada y modificada en otras zonas del código. En ese caso podemos generar una variable que será única en el ámbito de un mismo archivo PHP concatenando a la variable estática `__FILE__` que contiene la ruta completa al script un sufijo de nuestra elección (`_error` en nuestro ejemplo):

```
try { ... }
catch (SoapFault $ex) {
    $GLOBALS[__FILE__ . '_error'] = $ex->faultcode;

//RESPUESTA ANTE UNA EXCEPCIÓN

function wpse_form_response_output_ko( $output, $class, $content, $instance) {

    switch ($GLOBALS[__FILE__ . '_error']) {
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.IdUsuarioInvalido':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario no es válido.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.UsuarioExistente':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: el usuario ya existe.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;
        case 'Educativa.Aula.Error.ClaveUsuarioInvalida':
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: La clave no es valida.'));
            break;

        default:
            return sprintf( '<div class="wpcf7-response-output wpcf7-display-none wpcf7-mail-sent-ng" role="alert" style="display: block;">%s</div>', __('Error: Ha ocurrido un fallo al enviar el formulario, revise bien los campos.'));
            break;
    }
}


    // MOSTRAMOS LA RESPUESTA PERSONALIZADA
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_response_output', 'wpse_form_response_output_ko', 10, 4 );

    // ANULAMOS EMAIL DE CONFIRMACIÓN SI HAY EXCEPCIÓN
    add_filter( 'wpcf7_skip_mail',  '__return_true' );


    // EMAIL CON DEBUG (COMENTAR AL FINALIZAR)
    mail_debug($ex);

}
```

Con esta última alternativa minimizamos el riesgo de colisión de variables globales.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.
Si, eso elimina el caso de la variable no definida, pero me aparece como vacía al ejecutar la función. Haciendo var_dump me da estos resultados:

var_dump en el código catch: 
string(38) "xxx.Aula.Error.IdUsuarioInvalido"

var_dump en la función, antes del switch:
string(0) ""

Comment: ¿Usas la variable `$error` en otro sitio? El problema radica en que si usas en otro sitio la variable global `$error` tendrás problemas. Prueba con `$GLOBALS` como te he puesto en el segundo ejemplo y si sigue sin funcionar cámbiale el nombre al índice y llámalo, por ejemplo `$GLOBALS['mi_error_personalizado']` o, si lo prefieres, `$GLOBALS[__FILE__ . '_error']`. Ese último es un truco un poco sucio para evitar que la variable global creada en otro lugar pueda afectar a la tuya (reducimos la probabilidad de colisión al mismo archivo).

Comment: Fantástico caballero, ha funcionado con `$GLOBALS[__FILE__ . '_mi_error_personalizado']` ( ya para aislarlo al 100% jeje) muchisimas gracias y muy amable! :)

Comment: De nada, voy a poner también esa opción en la respuesta por si a otra persona pudiera ayudarle :)